# Ruby on Rails - Pass value from Javascript to Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete field into my `_form.html.erb` to allow the user to enter `Categories` and save the object.

I was following this [Railscast video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMz8HmrQ350) for setting up the autocomplete, but it was for searching.

// application.js

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: "/search_suggestions"
});

$('#tags').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
    $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
});
```

With this, I can populate the recommendations with the correct values, and get a callback when a user selects a value.

// _form.html.erb

```
<div id="tagsname"></div>

<%= bootstrap_form_for(group) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
    <%= f.static_control label: "Categories" do %>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="tags"/>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

How do I pass them back to the Model?

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the `Model` you mean in a question?

Comment: I have a `Group` model that I'm trying to add the `Categories` to.

Comment: You pass parameters from the client to the model by creating a route and a controller action.

Comment: @max, Can you please give me an example as an answer?